# Query Unmapped Columns in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that is mapped to a table using NHibernate. The problem is that only some of the properties are mapped to columns in the table. This is fine because the only columns we use for display are mapped, however I was wondering if there is any way to query against other columns in the table that aren't mapped to properties in my class.

For example we have a table with the following columns:

```
Customer
-----------
CustomerId
Name
DateCreated
```

and we have an object

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public virtual string name {get;set;}
}
```

and `name` and `customerId` are mapped however `DateCreated` is not because we never display it anywhere. We would like to query the `Customer` table for customers that were created by a certain date. Is there any way to do this **without** mapping the `DateCreated`?  Also it would be preferable to do this using the criteria API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ayende Rahien posted an article which describes specifying `access="noop"` in the mapping to specify query-only properties. See [NHibernate – query only properties](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx). I have not tried this myself.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the property element - is there a trick to it?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I just tested this as well, did not work. According to the docs `noop` is not valid for the `access` attribute on the `property` element (see [reference](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-property)).

Answer (score 5):

Is using a plain SQL query out of the question?  I'm not able to test it right now, but I would imagine that you could query on unmapped fields, as long as your query returns something that Hibernate can map to an object.  (sorry if this was already ruled out as an option)

EDIT: This seems to work:

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(
                "select c.* " +
                "from Customer c " +
                "where c.CreateDate > :CreateDate");

query.SetDateTime("CreateDate", new DateTime(2009, 3, 14));
query.AddEntity(typeof(Customer));

IList<Customer> results = query.List<Customer>();
```

Comment: (my column names were slightly different)

Comment: it's not out of the question but I'd really like to be able to use the criteria api if at all possible. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 5):

With HQL/Criteria queries, NHibernate can only work with what has been mapped (although raw SQL is still an option as Andy White has pointed out). If you want to use Criteria queries, you have to map the column.

However, NHibernate is not restricted to using publicly accessible members. So, if you want to keep hiding the `CreateDate` field, declare a private (maybe read-only?) property.  Alternatively, you can skip the property and instruct NHibernate to use field level access by setting `access="field"` on the property element in the mapping.

I know you wanted to do this without mapping the field, but I just don't think it's possible (without modifying the NHibernate source ;).  Still, if you're querying against the field then the field has some relevance to your domain and therefore probably deserves to be mapped into it, and with a private or protected member you can keep the information hiding in place.

Comment: I tried using a private property, but you can't have a private virtual property in C# and nhibernate needs a virtual property :(