# Filter using criteria on not mapped column

Tags: nhibernate

I have a entity mapped to a table and an extra column which is not mapped.

Is it possible to make a select using criteria and filter on that extra column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Unmapped Columns in NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657170/query-unmapped-columns-in-nhibernate)

Comment: almost, just that mapping the columns is not an acceptable solution for me

Answer (score 2):

The definitive answer: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx

This question is a duplicate: [Query Unmapped Columns in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657170/query-unmapped-columns-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Expression.Sql` to create an arbitrary filter that can include unmapped columns. Lots of [examples around](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22Expression.Sql%22+nhibernate).